# Clamp GameObject into isometric camera viewport

Tags: unity, c#, mathematics, isometric, projection

I'm using this code to move an object into an isometric projection, as viewed by an orthographic camera tilted with Euler angles (30, 45, 0)

```
[SerializeField] private Camera cam;
[SerializeField] private Transform target;
[SerializeField] private float speed;

private Vector3 forward, right;

private void Start()
{
    forward = cam.transform.forward;
    forward.y = 0;
    forward = Vector3.Normalize(forward);
    right = Quaternion.Euler(0, 90, 0) * forward;
}

private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse0))
    {
        var righMovement = right * speed * Time.deltaTime * (Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"));
        var upMovement = forward * speed * Time.deltaTime * (Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y"));

        if (righMovement != Vector3.zero && upMovement != Vector3.zero)
                target.forward = Vector3.Normalize(righMovement + upMovement);

            lastPosition += new Vector3
            {
                x = righMovement.x + upMovement.x,
                y = righMovement.y + upMovement.y,
                z = righMovement.z + upMovement.z
            };

            target.position = lastPosition;

            //target.position = Clamp(lastPosition);
        }
    }
}
```

At same time I want to clamp that object based on the screen size to avoid moving the target when it is off screen, so I made this:

```
private Vector3 Clamp(Vector3 position)
{
    var w2p = Camera.main.WorldToViewportPoint(position);

    w2p.x = Mathf.Clamp(w2p.x, .2f, .8f);
    w2p.y = Mathf.Clamp(w2p.y, .2f, .8f);

    return Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(w2p)
}
```

But I'm getting some weird behaviours, the X axis clamp is fine, but Z is not working at all, and Y is not behaving correctly when moving. It's quite probable I'm doing this in the wrong way. How should it be?

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/FrustumSizeAtDistance.html

all you need is this link. in perspective we dont have axact bound but we have bounds in distance. you have to calculate camera distance from you object and calculate bound on that distance.

if its in 3d you can calculate using below:

```
 public static class CameraExtensions
 {
     public static Bounds OrthographicBounds(this Camera camera)
     {
         float screenAspect = (float)Screen.width / (float)Screen.height;
         float cameraHeight = camera.orthographicSize * 2;
         Bounds bounds = new Bounds(
             camera.transform.position,
             new Vector3(cameraHeight * screenAspect, cameraHeight, 0));
         return bounds;
     }
 }
```

you can follow this thread for more info:

https://answers.unity.com/questions/501893/calculating-2d-camera-bounds.html

Comment: I forgot to say this camera is orthographic

Answer (score 0):

For any point on screen, there's a whole line of points in your world that map to that point.

Your current code is choosing the one that maintains the same depth from the camera, which may or may not be what you want.

An alternative would be to try to maintain the same height (y) in the world. That code would look like this:

```
private Vector3 Clamp(Vector3 worldPosition)
{
    // Cache this to avoid repeated searches.
    var camera = Camera.main;

    var viewportPoint = camera.WorldToViewportPoint(worldPosition);

    viewportPoint.x = Mathf.Clamp(viewportPoint.x, .2f, .8f);
    viewportPoint.y = Mathf.Clamp(viewportPoint.y, .2f, .8f);

    var ray = camera.ViewportPointToRay(viewportPoint);

    // Compute the distance along the ray where it crosses our y plane.
    float d = (position.y - ray.origin.y)/ray.direction.y;

    // Return that intersection point.
    return ray.GetPoint(d);
}
```